# Transformation between "map" and "odom" in tf

Tags: navigation, mapping, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Let's assume I am working on a localization algorithm and need to publish the transformation between "map" frame and "odom" frame. I already know he robot's location in "map" coordinates is PM, and its location in "odom" coordinates is PO,  if I publish a transformation using "map" as parent frame, and "odom" as the child frame, then this transformation should be PO-PM or PM-PO?

---

Update: Below is my code, is it correct?

```
tf::StampedTransform tf_map_to odom
// set up parent and child frames
tf_map_to_odom.frame_id_ = string("map");
tf_map_to_odom.child_frame_id_ = string("odom");

// set up publish rate
//ros::Rate loop_rate(100);

// main loop
tf_map_to_odom.stamp_ = ros::Time::now();

tf_map_to_odom.setOrigin(tf::Vector3(
   point_in_map.x - odom.pose.pose.position.x,
   point_in_map.y - odom.pose.pose.position.y, 
   0));

tf::Quaternion q;
q.setRPY(0, 0, point_in_map.orientation);
tf::Quaternion qq;
quaternionMsgToTF(ddom.pose.pose.orientation, qq);
q = q * qq.inverse();
tf_map_to_odom.setRotation(q);

// broadcast transform
_tf_br.sendTransform(tf_map_to_odom);
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/309579/transformation-between-%22map%22-and-%22odom%22-in-tf/) by [AutoCar](https://answers.ros.org/users/35903/autocar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 102 on 2018-11-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

PM-PO, but you need to make sure you are not simply "subtracting", as you have to take care about the orientation of the frames as well.

As a simple example, assume `PM = (10,0,0)` in (x,y,yaw), PO  = `(2,0,0)`, you'd get MO = (8,0,0).

In `amcl` it is solved [like this](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/blob/melodic-devel/amcl/src/amcl_node.cpp#L1392-L1432) , e.g.

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2018-11-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1